# Why can you neglect higher order terms as a variable tends to zero?

Tags: calculus, approximation

If we have an expression involving various powers of some variable $x$, we often neglect 2nd or higher order terms as $x\to0$ as the higher powers become negligible compared to the lower powers. However the validity of this relies on the fact that $x<1$ so that $x^2<x$. This means that the values of $x$ for which the approximation is valid depends on the choice of units of $x$, which seems to make no sense at all!
Does anyone have an explanation for this? Thanks :)

Comment: There are no units at all in maths! Further more, when $x\to 0$, the real values of $x$ will eventually be smaller than $1$.

Comment: Thanks :) I was asking this on the context of physical questions, in which for example we may assume the oscillations of a pendulum are 'small' to neglect higher order terms. But how small is small enough will depend on the units we choose?

Comment: @user294388: You are neglecting the higher order terms in a unitless quantity, though. The approximation is $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ (and therefore $\sin(\theta) L \approx \theta L$), not $\sin(L) \approx L$. In fact, $\sin(x)$ only makes sense when $x$ is a unitless quantity. The same is true of most mathematical functions.

Comment: @Hurkyl oh yes of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x\to 0$, independently by the dimensions since we are dealing with unitless quantity, we can assume WLOG that eventually $x<1$ then we have that $x^2<<x$.

Comment: If $x$ is a dimensional quantity, then $x$ and $x^2$ have completely different dimensions; $x^2 << x$ doesn't really make sense. I.e. it's not really meaningful to compare an area of $1$ meter squared with a length of 10 meters.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes of course you are right! I need to specify better my " independently by the dimensions" .

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now!

Comment: @user294388 You are welcome! Bye